# SQL Server 2014 System Views poster

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint

I have the 2008 version of this poster. I really like it and I think it is a good way of understanding how all the pieces fit together. However, I don't know where to find newer versions of it such as SQL Server 2014 or 2016. Please if anyone can help show me where to find architectural diagrams for Microsoft Azure and Sharepoint in addition to that it will be highly appreciated.
   Thanks.